# Datatables with different headers and numbers of columns

Tags: datatables

Is it possible to do a table with a lot of headers and different numbers of columns, just like that?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/0LhJU.png

I've looked for this in several forums, but I didn't found any solution.

Thanks a lot,

Comment: Tables are fixed, you can have many columns but then it become inefficient. You would just have a database with several different tables, possibly linked with foreign keys, and use queries to join the data together

Comment: @TerenceSimpson Are you talking about the same kind of tables? Hover over the datatables tag and check the description.

Comment: @user23456659 I don't think it's possible.